# Android Importing exporting sqlite data

Tags: android, sqlite

So my idea is that i want to make it easy for people to convert over to my android app from someone else's. It seems as though i can import data into my database, correct me if i'm wrong, from a file. However, how can i (or another app available on the market) retreive the data from an app so that they (the user) can move it?

Comment: You can programatically insert data into Sqlite that you got from a file or user input or <anywhere>. Data is data.   If the other app implemented ContentProvider (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) it would be EZ. I seriously doubt most do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to extract data from an app and use it with you app, isn't it?

That depends os how the app has the data stored, and almost all apps have the data stored in a way that you can't access it if you app don't have permissions to access it, and if that app don't offers a way of getting the data, you will need root permissions to access it, and for that the device must be rooted.

All that assuming that the data is on the device. Right now there are apps that save the data on internet, so you have to connect to the server the app connects and, using the same credentials to log in that the original app does, log and retrieve the data, and for retrieving the data you will need to use the same calls that the original app does. This is not good because at anytime the server calls needed to login or retrieve data can change and your app will be broken.

In other words, is impossible to access other app data in a normal way if that app don't have an API for your app to retrieve data.

Also if the app have an option to export data, then the user can export the data to a file in a common format so your app can open it.